# Need help using Regex with brackets and OR operation

Tags: java, regex

This is the pattern I am trying to use :

```
house.*name.*((\"(.*)\")|(\((\".*\")\)))
```

These are the strings I want to match against :

```
house with name = "avilla"
house with name in ("avilla","bvilla")
```

I am trying to get a **group** such that it returns the following results:

```
avilla
avilla","bvilla
```

I tried a lot but one way or the other I am unable to get the group. I am **able to match** but what I want is I **should get the group**. Any kind of help in appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the two results:

```
(?<=house with name (?:=|in) )(?:[(]?\"(.*(?=\"$|\")))
```

here is the test link:
https://regex101.com/r/DtIhJA/1/

As you wish, it gives you group for your 1st input:

```
avilla
```

for the 2nd input:

```
avilla","bvilla
```

Comment: This seems good but how to use < (?<=house .* name > because only 'house' and 'name' should match strictly . I really am not concerned with 'with' in between. I tried to edit your pattern but it gives error. Can you please help once more?

Comment: if you only want to capture results in the groups, you can use non-capture group. `(?:house whatever.....name (?:=|in)....` @Vinay

Comment: Thanks @Kent. I finally made some more changes to your pattern and finally got what I was looking for. You really helped me with your knowledge. I am really grateful. Thanks

Comment: @Vinay you're welcome. It's great to hear that you made it work.

Answer (score 1):

If the parenthesis can be optional, but there has to be a closing `"` you could also use a capture group optionally matching the parenthesis.

```
\bhouse with name (?:=|in) \(?(\".*?\")\)?(?!\S)
```

- `\bhouse with name`
- `(?:=|in)`  Optionally match `=`  or `in`
- `\(?` Match an optional parenthesis
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\".*?\"` Match `"`, then as least chars as possible till `"`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\)?` Match an optional parenthesis
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ziep1W/1)

To match up the double quotes and the parenthesis, you might also either use the lookbehind and match what is in between the double quotes or use the lookbehind and match what is between the parenthesis using an alternation.

```
(?<=house with name (?:=|in) \")[^\"]+(?=\")|(?<=house with name (?:=|in) \()[^()]+(?=\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xay81v/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot . I got the answer already but your answer is helpful too.